# Usage of python bytearray

Tags: python, string, performance, arrays

I was wondering whether using bytearray for constructing a string like.

```
def build_string(pairs):
    data = ''
    for key, value in pairs.iteritems():
        data = data + '\r\n' + '%s:%s' % (key, value)
    data = data + '\r\n\r\n'
    return data
```

would be slower than.

```
def build_string(pairs):
    data = bytearray()
    for key, value in pairs.iteritems():
        data.extend('%s:%s\r\n' % (key, value))
    data.extend('\r\n')
    return data
```

Answer (score 6):

You should just use `str.join()`

You generally shouldn't need to include the carriage return (`\r`).  Python has universal newline support.  It will use the correct line ending for the OS.

```
return '\n'.join('{0}:{1}'.format(k, v) for k, v in pairs.iteritems()) + '\n\n'
```

Comment: i have used this code. http://codepad.org/zvHgPP0f  it seems test2 is faster than both test1 and test3

Comment: @tau Only for short lists and short strings.  Make the list longer, or use longer key and value strings and it gets exponentially worse.  The bytearray version can actually be a bit faster, but it depends on whether you want to support non-ascii or not.